# How to skip blank rows in CsvHelper >28.0.0?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

CsvHelper 28.0.0 changes the `ShouldSkipRecordArgs` from a property `string[] Record` to `IReaderRow Row`.  Although this interface exposes a `this` property, it does not implement IEnumerable.

Previously you could configure the `CsvReader` to skip blank rows by using `ShouldSkipRecord = x => x.Record.All(field => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field))`.  This is now no longer possible.

What is the recommended approach to skip blank rows as of 28.0.0?

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the commit where this change was made, thankfully the unit tests show the update.  The `string[] Record` property does still exist you just have to navigate to it.

Change:

`ShouldSkipRecord = x => x.Record.All(field => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field))`

To:

`ShouldSkipRecord = x => x.Row.Parser.Record?.All(field => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field)) ?? false`